# Difference between two versions of cross_entropy calculations in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, entropy

I'm using TensorFlow in order to train binary classification neural network.

In order to build the network, half-year ago I followed the tutorial in TensorFlow website - [Deep MNIST for Experts](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/mnist/pros/).

Today, when I comparing both codes (the one in the tutorial and the one I wrote), I can see a difference in the cross-entropy calculation. A difference that I can't tell why it's there.

In the **tutorial** the cross-entropy calculated as follows:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_))
```

While in **my code** the calculation is as follows:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
```

I'm new in Tensorflow, and I feel that I'm missing something. Mabey the difference is between two versions of the TensorFlow tutorials? **What is the actual difference between the two lines?**

Really appreciate your help. Thanks!

The relevant code from the tutorial:

```
    y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2
...
    cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_))
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

My code:

```
# load data
folds = build_database_tuple.load_data(data_home_dir=data_home_dir,validation_ratio=validation_ratio,patch_size=patch_size)

# starting the session. using the InteractiveSession we avoid build the entiee comp. graph before starting the session
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

# start building the computational graph
# the 'None' indicates the number of classes - a value that we wanna leave open for now
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, patch_size**2]) #input images - 28x28=784
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 2]) #output classes (using one-hot vectors)

# the vriables for the linear layer
W = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([(patch_size**2),2])) #weights - 784 input features and 10 outputs
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([2])) #biases - 10 classes

# initialize all the variables using the session, in order they could be used in it
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

# implementation of the regression model
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) + b)

# Done!

# FIRST LAYER:
# build the first layer
W_conv1 = weight_variable([first_conv_kernel_size, first_conv_kernel_size, 1, first_conv_output_channels]) # 5x5 patch, 1 input channel, 32 output channels (features)
b_conv1 = bias_variable([first_conv_output_channels])

x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1,patch_size,patch_size,1]) # reshape x to a 4d tensor. 2,3 are the image dimensions, 4 is ine color channel

# apply the layers
h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

# SECOND LAYER:
# 64 features each 5x5 patch
W_conv2 = weight_variable([sec_conv_kernel_size, sec_conv_kernel_size, patch_size, sec_conv_output_channels])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([sec_conv_output_channels])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

# FULLY CONNECTED LAYER:
# 1024 neurons, 8x8 - new size after 2 pooling layers
W_fc1 = weight_variable([(patch_size/4) * (patch_size/4) * sec_conv_output_channels, fc_vec_size])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([fc_vec_size])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, (patch_size/4) * (patch_size/4) * sec_conv_output_channels])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

# dropout layer - meant to reduce over-fitting
keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

# READOUT LAYER:
# softmax regression
W_fc2 = weight_variable([fc_vec_size, 2])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([2])

y_conv=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2)

# TRAIN AND EVALUATION:
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y_conv), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())
```

Answer (score 3):

The difference is small but quite significative.

softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits takes logits (real numbers without any range limit), passes them through the softmax function and then computes the cross-entropy. Combining both into one function is to apply some optimizations to improve numerical accuracy.

The second code just applies cross-entropy directly to y_conv, which seems to be the output of a softmax function. This is correct, and both should give similar but not the same results, softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits is superior because of numerical stability. Just remember to give it logits and not the output of a softmax.